# Determination of complex logarithm on spiral set

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

So, I was trying to understand the determination of the complex logarithm for sets 'trickier' than $\mathbb{C}$ minus a half line, and took the spiral $V=\{r\cdot e^{ir}\colon r\geq 0\}$ ( which begins at $0$ and rotates counterclockwise), and defined $S=\mathbb{C}\backslash V$ the set on which to find the logarithm determination. My first idea, since our teacher had done this in other examples, was to find a  continuous determination of the argument $\theta:S\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ and from it take $g(z)=log(|z|)+i\theta(z)$ to be the new determination of the logarithm, but I can't see how to get neither the $\theta$ to  be continuous on $S$ nor an immediate new determination for the logarithm. Can you give me any clues on how to proceed? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
Given a point $z\in S$ there is a unique $\tau\in[0,2\pi[\>$ such that $z=|z|\,e^{i\tau}$. Draw the ray from $0$ through $z$. This ray intersects the spiral $V$ in two points $a$, $b$ such that $z\in[a,b]$, and there is  an $n\geq0$ such that
$$a=(2n\pi+\tau)e^{i\tau},\qquad b=\bigl(2(n+1)\pi+\tau\bigr)e^{i\tau}\ .$$One has $|a|<|z|<|b|$, so that
$$2n\pi+\tau<|z|<2(n+1)\pi+\tau\ ,$$
or $$2n\pi<|z|-\tau<2(n+1)\pi\ .$$ This implies
$$n=\left\lfloor{|z|-\tau\over2\pi}\right\rfloor\ ,$$
so that your desired "spiral logarithm" $\ell$ can be written as
$$\ell(z)=\log|z|+\left(2\pi\left\lfloor{|z|-\tau\over2\pi}\right\rfloor+\tau\right)i\qquad(z\in S)\ .$$You can easily check that the discontinuity along the positive real axis is only apparent. In reality the function $\ell$ is analytic in $S$,
and satisfies
$$\ell'(z)={1\over z}\qquad(z\in S)\ .$$